# Imported ES6 module is not executed after processing in parcel

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, parceljs

When using vanilla JS

module.js

```
console.log("modulejs");
const  a =1;
class Test{

}
export  {Test}
```

index.js

```
import {Test} from "./module.js"
```

I get the console.log message just via importing a class.

But when working with parcel on my TypeScript, the console.log is not executed.

Answer (score -1):

**Update (June 2021):**

This issue seems to be fixed with the latest versions of parcel2.

See [the example above in the Parcel REPL](https://parcel2-repl.vercel.app/#JTdCJTIyY3VycmVudFByZXNldCUyMiUzQSUyMkphdmFzY3JpcHQlMjIlMkMlMjJvcHRpb25zJTIyJTNBJTdCJTIybWluaWZ5JTIyJTNBZmFsc2UlMkMlMjJzY29wZUhvaXN0JTIyJTNBdHJ1ZSUyQyUyMnNvdXJjZU1hcHMlMjIlM0FmYWxzZSUyQyUyMnB1YmxpY1VybCUyMiUzQSUyMiUyRl9fcmVwbF9kaXN0JTIyJTJDJTIydGFyZ2V0VHlwZSUyMiUzQSUyMmJyb3dzZXJzJTIyJTJDJTIydGFyZ2V0RW52JTIyJTNBbnVsbCUyQyUyMm91dHB1dEZvcm1hdCUyMiUzQW51bGwlMkMlMjJobXIlMjIlM0FmYWxzZSUyQyUyMm1vZGUlMjIlM0ElMjJwcm9kdWN0aW9uJTIyJTJDJTIycmVuZGVyR3JhcGhzJTIyJTNBZmFsc2UlMkMlMjJ2aWV3U291cmNlbWFwcyUyMiUzQWZhbHNlJTJDJTIyZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTdEJTJDJTIyYXNzZXRzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVCJTIyc3JjJTJGaW5kZXguanMlMjIlMkMlMjJpbXBvcnQlMjAlN0JUZXN0JTdEJTIwZnJvbSUyMCU1QyUyMi4lMkZtb2R1bGUuanMlNUMlMjIlMjIlMkMxJTVEJTJDJTVCJTIyc3JjJTJGbW9kdWxlLmpzJTIyJTJDJTIyY29uc29sZS5sb2coJTVDJTIybW9kdWxlanMlNUMlMjIpJTNCJTVDbmNvbnN0JTIwJTIwYSUyMCUzRDElM0IlNUNuY2xhc3MlMjBUZXN0JTdCJTVDbiU1Q24lN0QlNUNuZXhwb3J0JTIwJTIwJTdCVGVzdCU3RCUyMiU1RCU1RCU3RA==).

---

What might be happening is that parcel is determining that the `Test` class import is actually unused in `index.js`, so it's tree-shaking the `module.js` entirely.

If you change `index.js` to:

```
import { Test } from "./module.js";
const myInstance = new Test();
```

You should see that it does not get tree-shaken, and the `console.log` statement is executed.

If the code you want to import is under your control, I wouldn't recommend having side effects like that `console.log` statements. If it's unavoidable, I *think* you can tell parcel not to tree-shake either by setting `sideEffects: true` in your `package.json` (see [docs](https://v2.parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/)).

(This answer is assuming you are using [Parcel 2](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-2-beta-1-improved-stability-tree-shaking-source-map-performance-and-more-78179779e8b7)).